Generalized Inverse of Submatrices
Consider a symmetric and positive semi-definite $n\times n$-matrix $\Sigma$. For $k = 1,\dots, n$, let $\Sigma_k$ denote $\Sigma$'s Leading Principal Minor of of order $k$, i.e., the submatrix of $\Sigma$ that is obtained when the last $n-k$ rows and $n-k$ columns are deleted.
Goal: invert $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2, \dots, \Sigma_n$.
The usual inverse may not exist for each $\Sigma_k$. However, since each $\Sigma_k$ is symmetric, we can easily construct a pseudo inverse $\Sigma_k^{+}$ for $\Sigma_k$.
Problem: computing $\Sigma_1^+, \Sigma_2^+,\dots,\Sigma_n^+$ takes very long for my application. For $k = 1,2,\dots,n$, I compute the eigen decomposition of $\Sigma_k$: $$\Sigma_k = V_k^{~}\Lambda_k^{~}V_k^{-1},$$ where $V_k$ is an $(n-k)\times(n-k)$ orthonormal matrix and $\Lambda_k$ is a $(n-k)\times(n-k)$ diagonal matrix. Given $\Lambda_k$, I construct a new matrix $\Lambda_k^{+}$ by inverting all non-zero elements. Finally, I put $$\Sigma_k^{+} = V_k^{~}\Lambda_k^+V_k^{-1}.$$
Is there any hope that I could exploit the submatrix structure to speed up my computations?
